# Texture from video tag leaks memory

Tags: javascript, three.js, html5-video

I am creating a THREE.js (r78) texture from a `video` tag and updating the texture 60 times per second by setting `needsupdate=true` in `requestanimationframe`. My issue is I see memory leaking in the Chrome Task Manager. Specifically, for the task **GPU Process** under the column **Memory** (not **GPU Memory**), the value increases over time.

The video file is MP4, H.264, 60 fps. My code is posted below. I wanted to vet this on stackoverflow.com before I submit a new THREE.js issue on github.com.

```
    var video = document.createElement('video');
    video.src = 'test1.mp4';
    video.loop = true;
    video.load(); 
    video.play();

    video.onloadedmetadata = function() {
        initScene();
        animate();
    };

    var scene, camera, renderer, object;

    function initScene() {
        const W = 1280;
        const H = 720;
        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(30, W/H, 1, 5000);
        camera.position.z = 1000;
        object = makeVideoObject(video.videoWidth, video.videoHeight);
        scene = new THREE.Scene();
        scene.add(object);
        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias:true, alpha:true});
        renderer.setSize(W, H);
        document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
    }

    function animate() {
        object.material.map.needsUpdate = true;
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    }

    function makeVideoObject(w, h) {
        var texture = new THREE.Texture(video);
        texture.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
        texture.magFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
        var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map:texture });
        var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(w, h, 1, 1);
        return new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    }
```

BTW, I also tried creating the texture from a `canvas` tag, and updating it's context by calling `context.drawImage(video, 0, 0)` before setting `needsupdate=true`. This also leaks memory.

**EDIT**
I submitted an issue. See https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/9440

Comment: Can you try [webglinspector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/webgl-inspector/ogkcjmbhnfmlnielkjhedpcjomeaghda) to check if images are kept after loading them.

Comment: @Gero3, In the textures tab (my 1st time using WebGL inspector) the only object listed is my movie file. No other images.

Comment: What browsers did you use??

Comment: I also inspected using my alternative code which draws the video frames onto a canvas. Same thing, in the textures tab there is only a single texture which updates each time I click Capture.

Comment: Did you try using firefox already??

Comment: No leak in firefox

Answer (score 0):

I'm almost certain this is a Chrome issue.

The issue does not occur in Firefox.

Similar issues concerning GPU Process memory leaks in Chrome have been reported:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=403471
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=470234

I reported this as a new issue:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=634012